# combining arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I have three separate 1d arrays of a list of numbers, their squares and cubes (created by a 'for' loop). 
I would like these arrays to appear in three corresponding columns, however I have tried the column_stack function and python says its not defined. I have read about the vstack and hstack functions but am confused about which to use and what exactly they do. 
My code so far reads;

```
import numpy
makearange = lambda a: numpy.arange(int(a[0]),int(a[1]),int(a[2]))
x = makearange(raw_input('Enter start,stop,increment: ').split(','))
y = numpy.zeros(len(x), dtype=int)
z = numpy.zeros(len(x), dtype=int)
for i in range(len(x)):
    y[i] = x[i]**2
for i in range(len(x)):
    z[i] = x[i]**3
print 'original array: ',x
print 'squared array: ',y
print 'cubed array: ', z
```

I would appreciate any advice

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you define `y` and `z` directly?

```
y = x**2
z = x**3
```

and then simply:

```
stacked = np.column_stack((x,y,z))
```

which gives you a 2D array of shape `len(x) * 3`

Comment: I understand this is possible but have been instructed to use a for loop to learn the technique. Inputting this into my code results in [(2, 4, 8), (4, 16, 64), (6, 36, 216), (8, 64, 512)]

Comment: @Candace - numpy is a powerful tool perfect for manipulation of such data. If you want/have to use a for loop "to learn", then add the `homework` tag to your question.

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy
makearange = lambda a: numpy.arange(int(a[0]),int(a[1]),int(a[2]))
x = makearange(raw_input('Enter start,stop,increment: ').split(','))
a = np.zeros((len(x),3))
a[:,0] = x
a[:,1] = x**2
a[:,2] = x**3
```

When using arrays you should avoid for loops as much as possible, that's kind of the point of arrays.

`a = np.zeros((len(x),3))` creates an array of length same as x and with 3 columns
`a[:,i]` is a reference to the 'i'th column of this array (i.e. select all values (denoted by `:`) along this (`i`) column)

I would strongly recommend you look at the [Numpy Tutorial](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/quickstart.html).

Answer (score 0):

You do want [column_stack](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.column_stack.html). Have you tried:

```
w = numpy.column_stack((x,y,z))
print(w)
```